# Image Rotation Matching by comparing 2 lists/lines for similarity OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, rotation

I take a template

[image]

and sample 8 points from it (now 36). Each little dot is a mask and i take the average value from that little dotted area and i add them to a list.

[image]

It ends up looking something like these:

[203, 176, 160, 174, 185, 185, 152, 136, 131, 131, 131, 131, 131, 137, 144, 133, 131, 130, 130, 130, 131, 130, 139, 160, 168, 150, 141, 160, 186, 201, 209, 214, 216, 216, 216, 217]

[194, 207, 216, 217, 217, 217, 217, 217, 217, 216, 214, 170, 148, 159, 171, 175, 165, 136, 131, 131, 130, 131, 149, 170, 151, 132, 131, 131, 131, 131, 134, 169, 172, 141, 141, 172]

[131, 131, 131, 141, 171, 164, 133, 141, 178, 197, 213, 216, 216, 216, 217, 217, 217, 217, 217, 216, 175, 153, 163, 174, 183, 171, 142, 132, 130, 130, 131, 161, 170, 149, 131, 131]

[131, 131, 131, 131, 153, 151, 136, 130, 131, 131, 131, 130, 130, 150, 164, 149, 134, 145, 172, 195, 205, 215, 216, 217, 217, 217, 216, 216, 195, 161, 168, 179, 192, 171, 152, 131]

Its easier to visualize them with a Plot. The RED line refers directly to the 1st sad teenager who is standing upright. (also known as Zero degree position). I need to find someway of comparing a line or list to the RED line/list. This way i can figure out what rotation the other teenagers are at given that the RED line is the Zero.

The values are not the same but very close to each other and obviously the lines are just off shifted meaning that the images are rotated. Are there any functions i can call that would do this kind of thing or some way i could process these to give me the rotation? Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you convert your images to polar coordinates and do template matching on those. In the polar coordinates, shifts correspond to rotations.

Comment: Can you provide data of two rotated images(about 180 to each other)? I wanna try something out.

Comment: I guess you are trying to calculate the rotation angle in a given template by comparing it with the known lists of points, yes? Have you tried comparing the lists using some distance metric? Of course, this will tell you the list that is the closest to your unlabeled points, so it would be an approximation.

Comment: @eldesgraciado Yes, that is correct. I have not tried a distance metric yet because im unsure of how that would work. I'd like to try least squares but im not sure if that would be effective. An approximation is fine because all i would have to do it snap it to the nearest 90 degree angle.

Comment: @RahulKedia I tried creating 2 sets of data points using 2 images that were 180 out but minAreaRect function only gives angles from 0-90, so instead I just posted all the data for the 4 images. Visually it looks like this should include a 180* set of lists but you'll have to determine what 2 lists to use. I added the lists to my original post.